# Cant find Azure VM Option B-series at enum VirtualMachineSizeTypes

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-java-sdk

At com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.VirtualMachineSizeTypes (Virtual Machine options enum) I cant found items of B-series as mention at [Azure Linux Virtual Machines Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/). there is any reason for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B-series size names like this:

`Standard_B1s`, `Standard_B1ms`, `Standard_B2s`,`Standard_B2ms`,`Standard_B4ms`,`Standard_B8ms`

[image]

More information about virtual machine size type in java sdk, please refer to this [article](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/VirtualMachineSizeTypes.html).

Here a [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-b-series-our-new-burstable-vm-size/) introduce Azure B-Series, please refer to it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I found that B-Series has been added to the Enum at version 1.8. I currently use 1.6.